# Does there exist any syntactic sugar for the Javascript prototype field?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there any way to clean up all the `Obj.prototype.field =` statements in my javascript code? I am using jQuery. I want to do the same thing except not have every other word in my code be `prototype`. Maybe what I'm asking is impossible -- if so, just let me know and that will be the answer.

I found this to be an ungoogleable question because there is a js library named "Prototype"...

Comment: Coffeescript is pretty good syntactic sugar.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately coffee isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). The properties of the second argument will be copied over to the first one:

```
$.extend(Obj.prototype,{
   field1: "hi there",
   func1: function(){
     //do stuff
   }
});
```

This is what jQuery uses internally, jQuery.fn being an alias for jQuery.prototype:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
   attr: function( name, value ) {
      return jQuery.access( this, jQuery.attr, name, value, arguments.length > 1 );
   },

   removeAttr: function( name ) {
       return this.each(function() {
                jQuery.removeAttr( this, name );
        });
   }, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like

```
var p = Obj.prototype;

p.newMethod = function(window.alert("Hi! I live"));
p.newProperty = false;
```

Comment: Um, yea.  I meant to have that `var` there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just:

```
Obj.prototype = {
  run: function(){},
  fooBar: function(test1,test2){}  
};
```

?

Comment: Disadvantage - if applicable: this overwrites the entire prototype object. You also lose links to the superclass, and any properties and methods defined previously.

Comment: That would replace `Obj.prototype` and loose all the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the "extend" functions of libraries like jQuery and YUI3

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/yui-extend.html
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/yui-extend.html

Also look at merge (jQuery, YUI3) and augment (YUI3) and at the usage.